# Why is this program not working? (Program to copy contents of file to another)

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

Sorry for the noob question, I am new to C++. I am trying to write a program to copy a file to another file, line by line. This is not throwing any error, its running but its not creating the destination file.

Let me know where the error is..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  ifstream fin;
  ofstream fout;
  char line[255];

  if (argc < 3) {
    cout << "ERROR - Incorrect number of arguments" << endl;
  } else {
    if (std::ifstream(argv[1])) {
      if (std::ifstream(argv[2])) {
        cout << "ERROR - Destination file already exists" << endl;
      } else {
        fin.open(argv[1], ios::in);
        fin.open(argv[2], ios::out);

        while(fin >> line) {
          cout << line << endl;
          fout << line << endl;
        }

        fin.close();
        fout.close();
      }
    } else {
      cout << "ERROR - Source file does not exist" << endl;
    }

  }

  return 0;  
}
```

Update: I got it working after I changed it to

```
ifstream fin(argv[1]);
ofstream fout(argv[2]);
```

But its copying weirdly. Its not copying whole lines, its copying like this:

```
#include
<iostream>
#include
<fstream>
using
namespace
std;
int
main(int
argc,
char
*argv[])
{
string
line;
if
(argc
<
3)
{
cout
<<
"ERROR
-
Incorrect
number
of
arguments"
<<
endl;
}
else
{
if
(std::ifstream(argv[1]))
{
if
(std::ifstream(argv[2]))
{
cout
<<
"ERROR
-
Destination
file
already
exists"
<<
endl;
}
else
{
ifstream
fin(argv[1]);
ofstream
fout(argv[2]);
while(fin
>>
line)
{
cout
<<
line
<<
endl;
fout
<<
line
<<
endl;
}
fin.close();
fout.close();
}
}
else
{
cout
<<
"ERROR
-
Source
file
does
not
exist"
<<
endl;
}
}
return
0;
}
```

How canI get it to copy including whitespace, and treating whole lines as whole lines?

Update: Got it working:

```
while(getline(fin, line)) {
  cout << line << endl;
  fout << line << endl;
}
```

Comment: Check those `open` calls again...

Comment: it shoul be fout.open , the second declaration... i think it is copy paste mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `fin.open(argv[2], ios::out);` to `fout.open(argv[2], ios::out);`

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what I was missing.